# Fetch: how to use etags?

Tags: javascript, json, header, fetch, etag

I'm planning to use Etags to validate the edited item to avoid mid-air collisions (if the item has been modified by other processes or users in the DB). here is the **plan**:

- Client calls RESTful API, gets an Etag from header, stores it in the item object.
- When user wants to make changes to the item, the Etag is sent to the
  RESTful API as If-Match header, API validates that against the
  current record and saves if valid and rejects it with the code 412 if
  not
- If rejected, client displays an error and tells user to refresh the
  page

**Questions:**

Is this a good approach?

How to store it nicely in item object using fetch? More precisely, how to combine the header value (Etag) with what comes back from `response.json()` in a nice way?

Thank you!

Comment: "how to combine ... in a nice way" --- it's a domain specific question. Ask your domain expert for that.

Comment: x.json() and x.headers() are siblings

Comment: Realise this is an old, old, question - but came across it and noticed it didn't have an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Is this a good approach?

Yes it is the intended use/documented approach.

2. How to store it nicely in item object using fetch?

This is debateable, but you could just wrap the etag header in with your data and pass that object. e.g.

```
    fetch('/data.json')
        .then(r => ({
            etag: r.headers.get('etag'), 
            json: r.json()
        }))
        .then(data => { 
            // do something with your etag and data
            console.log(data.etag);
            data.json.then(console.log)
        })
        .catch(console.error.bind(console));
```

See

> Avoiding mid-air collisions With the help of the ETag and the If-Match
> headers, you can detect mid-air edit collisions.
>
> For example, when editing a wiki, the current wiki content may be
> hashed and put into an Etag header in the response:
>
> ETag: "33a64df551425fcc55e4d42a148795d9f25f89d4" When saving changes
> to a wiki page (posting data), the POST request will contain the
> If-Match header containing the ETag values to check freshness against.
>
> If-Match: "33a64df551425fcc55e4d42a148795d9f25f89d4" If the hashes
> don't match, it means that the document has been edited in-between and
> a 412 Precondition Failed error is thrown.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag